# firefox addon attaching workers to tabs

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

In my main index.js I am listening for tab ready events:

```
tabs.on('ready', function(tab){
  deploy_scripts(tab)
})

var deploy_scripts = function deploy_scripts(tab) {
  tab.my_content_scripts = tab.attach({
    contentScriptFile: [<files>]
  })
  tab.my_content_scripts.port.on("message_from_content_script", function(msg){
    tabs.activeTab.my_content_scripts.port.emit("message_to_content_script", <some_data>)
  })
}
```

This will basically deploy some content scripts to a tab when that tab receives a page load event. Since the .attach() method returns a worker I assign that worker to the tab as a property.

When I access a tab later through tabs.activeTab the worker still exists as a property on that tab and I send a message to the worker using port. I do a similar thing elsewhere in my addon and it works fine but for some reason the script will not receive the message for this particular case.

I'm receiving the message like this in the content script I deploy

```
self.port.on("message_to_content_script", function(msg){
  // do something with data
})
```

There is no error being thrown from my index.js file since tabs.activeTab.my_content_scripts.port.emit exists but in spite of that my content script does not receive anything.

Comment: Your `emit` code is inside a `"messages"` listener. Does it even run? Do you send this message `"messages"` from the attached content scripts? `"messages"` is a terrible name for a message btw

Comment: @minj yea, I placed a console.log before the emit and that gets run and there is no error thrown as the emit runs. I understand "messages" is a terrible name but that was for the example. I'll edit it.

Comment: Why not reuse `tab` instead of `tabs.activeTab`? They may not be the same